# Visual Studio Addin Margin position

Tags: .net, visual-studio, margin

I need move margin to left text
Sorry for my english :(

[I need to move it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Z9n.png)

[This is my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXj16.png)

Comment: Use the https://hydernaji15-hotmail.tinytake.com/sf/NTM3MTY4XzI3OTY3MTI Decrease and increase indent to position your code.

Comment: Please, please add the code to your question as **text** rather than an image. It makes it so much harder for people to help you if they have to click on an image, squint to read the code, then maybe type the code in on their own computer to text/fix it. Many thanks.